# For loop, remove only 1 value even if shown multiple times || Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using MYSQL as my database for a command. I used a for loop to find the value given by the user.
`^pet add <rarity> <type> | ^pet add common Black`
I spent 7 hours figuring out how to get the for loop to then rewrite it last night.

I want to loop through the table column "common" and search for the type the user enters.
Just like the example; if I wanted to add Black to my pet list, I only want to remove one from the table.

I got it to search through the table for the type the user wants, but every time I want to remove only one instance of "Black" It either removes it partially correct, removes all of them or removes a value of "White" instead.
I've done a lot of testing, I couldn't find good examples of each issue it gave me.
[image]

I've also caught this issue, but I believe I fixed it with
`if (!rows[0].common.includes(bunPet)) return;`
[image]

```
case "common":
let commonCheck = rows[0].common.split(", ");
if (commonCheck.length <= 1) return message.reply('Please get another bun for your Common hold before setting a pet.');

    for (i = 0; i < commonCheck.length; i++) {
        let commonMatch = commonCheck[i].match(bunPet);
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM holds WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
            let alreadyRan = rows[0].pets;

            if (alreadyRan === bunPet) {
                return console.log('Already ran')
            } else {
                con.query(`SELECT * FROM bun WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    if (commonMatch) {
                        sql = `UPDATE bun SET common = '${commonCheck.join(", ")}' WHERE id = ${message.author.id}`;
                        con.query(sql);
                        con.query(`SELECT * FROM holds WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                                                    
                            sql = `UPDATE holds SET pets = '${bunPet}' WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`;
                            con.query(sql);
                        });
                        message.reply(`**${bunPet}** is now your current pet!\n**Your last pet has been removed.**`)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more digging inside other SO posts and found a fix.
Instead of using a for loop and searching through the whole list and trying to stop it from running on each value; I can use a indexOf search in a splice function.

```
case "common":
    let commonCheck = rows[0].common.split(", ");
    if (commonCheck.length <= 1) return message.reply('Please get another bun for your Common hold before setting a pet.');

    commonCheck.splice(commonCheck.indexOf(bunPet), 1);

    sql = `UPDATE bun SET common = '${commonCheck.join(", ")}' WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`;
    con.query(sql);

    con.query(`SELECT * FROM holds WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        sql = `UPDATE holds SET pets = '${bunPet}' WHERE id = '${message.author.id}'`;
        con.query(sql);
        message.reply(`**${bunPet}** is now your current pet!\n**Your last pet has been removed.**`);
    });
break;
```